# Using the Selenium ActionBuilder class with Ruby/Cucumber to implement drag and drop testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm trying to implement drag and drop testing for gridster using Selenium/Ruby.

The code infrastructure was set up by a previous QA tester and they left. Currently I'm the only one on the project and I only started using Selenium a few months ago (learned on the job). I want to explain my lack of knowledge in some areas.

I want to implement this method https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html#drag_and_drop_by-instance_method

The way I was planning on doing it was like this

```
Then(/^drag and drop the "(.*?)" right by (\d+) and down by (\d+)$/) do   
|draggable, right_by, down_by|
    driver = TestSupport.driver
    diver2 = WebDriver.driver
    dragging_instance = Navigation.instance
    dragging_instance.wait_until_action_element_visible(draggable, 40)
    driver2.action.drag_and_drop_by(draggable, right_by, down_by).perform
end
```

I've always tried replacing `WebDriver` with `ActionBuilder`. But when I run the test it says that both `WebDriver` and `ActionBuilder` are uninstantiated constants.

I did some research online and I found an article saying it may be due to a missing gem. But when I open up the gem list, I see this:

> gem 'selenium-webdriver',     '=2.41.0'

So it looks like the gem is there....and I'm not really sure how to proceed or what the problem is.

Comment: Is that `WebDriver` the module in Selenium or your own class? If it is the Selenium one, you probably need to do `Selenium::WebDriver`?

Comment: Are you talking about the link I provided? It's in Selenium already. So would i do something along the lines of driver=Selenium::WebDriver?

Comment: I was referring to the `driver2 = WebDriver.driver` line in your code. If that `WebDriver` is the Selenium module, it should be `Selenium::WebDriver`.